# What is good combat exp on Runescape?

Tags: runescape

What enemy would be best for me to train my melee skills?

My attack is 74 (Close to 75), 60 strength, 61 defense, and my constitution is 66.

I would like an enemy where I do not have to use much food/potions. I would also be able to make some money. Currently, I am using Ankou's, but I am looking for more exp.

For now, I am using an Abyssal Whip, and the Obsidian Shield. But once I hit 75 Attack, I will be using a Zamorak Godsword.

Comment: I think this is a too specific question. But maybe there is a list somewhere the best spots to level for certain types of characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really is no good monster that gives you great experience and good loot at your level.

If you want money, then training Slayer with the highest master is the way to go.

If you want experience, then you can try killing deadly red spiders (they give great experience). They are located in the Chaos Tunnels, Varrock Sewers, or inside the Karamja Volcano.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best training methods for you is dungeoneering. Dungeoneering will allow you to use good armor without the risk of losing it. If your out to make some cash however lesser demons commonly drop rune med helms which are 11k each.

Answer (score 0):

Since you sound like a member, do Slayer.  EoC kinda broke a lot of the usual training spots, but Slayer is all around good.